Clarification about those exercises on Topology
EDIT I miswrote, so I am editing the question. It was $2n-1$ not $2n+1$ in the first set. Sorry.
Good morning, this is my first question so I hope I'll do it good. What I need is some clarification on my reasoning (if it's wrong / incomplete / else) about this exercise in Topology. I have another one, so I will post a different question.
So the exercises demands me if $C, D$ are closed sets, where
$$C = \bigcup_{n \geq 1} C_n \qquad D = \bigcup_{n\geq 1} D_n$$
where again
$$C_n = \left\{ (x, y) \in\mathbb{R}^2: \frac{1}{2n} \leq \sqrt{x^2+y^2} \leq \frac{1}{2n-1} \right \} $$
$$D_n = \left\{ (x, y) \in\mathbb{R}^2: 2n-1 \leq \sqrt{x^2+y^2} \leq 2n\right \} $$
This is what I did.
First of all I tried to draw the sets $C_n, D_n$. For each $n$ of each set I got an annulus. For example for $C_1$ I have an annulus of external radius $\frac{1}{2n}$ and internal radius $\frac{1}{2n-1}$.
I forgot to specify that we work in the Euclidean standard topology.
My intuitions says that the union of $C_n$ should constitute a closed set. I tried to "paraphrase" the problem into a union of sets in $\mathbb{R}$, considering just the "space" between the radii as an closed and bounded interval. For example for $C_1$ the annulus as an interval in $\mathbb{R}$ runs from $\frac{1}{2}$ to $1$, hence it would be the interval $\left[\frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{3}\right]$.
With $C_2$ I would get $\left[\frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{3}\right]$ and so on. So eventually
$$\bigcup_{n\geq 1} \left[\frac{1}{2n}, \frac{1}{2n-1}\right]$$ would be closed.
But here is the trick When $n\to +\infty$ I obtain the origin, $0 \leq x^2+y^2 \leq 0$ which holds only for $x = y = 0$. Though this is a LIMIT, not explicitly contained in the set. Here I got confused, and thence the set wouldn't be closed.
Here I god confused also because of this:
A friend of mine told me that the writing $\bigcup_{n\geq 1} C_n$ is DIFFERENT from the writing $\bigcup_{n = 1}^{+\infty} C_n$, and since "infinite" is not in the union index it has no meaning to go up there.
But this then confuses me even more. Should I then stop to a generic $n$? How would this work?
This clearly affected all my reasonings, even about $D$...
Can you please help me?
Thank you very much.

Your friend told you wrong, the two notation usually refer to the same thing

Each $C_n$ is empty, and therefore $C=\emptyset$.

A locally finite family of closed sets has closed union. This works to show $D$ is closed. However this doesn't mean $C$ is closed since the family fails to be locally finite at the origin. And indeed it isn't, since $0\in\overline{C}\setminus C$.

@JoséCarlosSantos What? How can every $C_n$ be empty? It's an annulus contained between the two radii, the whole region inside is not empty. I don't understand...

@Jakobian A locally finite, yes. But as I said, here $n\to +\infty$ hence the union is not finite. What am I missing?

Since $\frac1{2n}>\frac1{2n+1}$, there is no number $t$ such that $\frac1{2n}\leqslant t\leqslant\frac1{2n+1}$. If you disagree, please provide an example of an element of $C_1$.

@JoséCarlosSantos Oh my... I completely miswrote. I meant $\frac{1}{2n-1}$ GOSH. Forgive me!!

Oh sorry, each $C_n$ is empty as @JoséCarlosSantos says

@Jakobian I realised that I wrote a malarkey. I meant $2n-1$... I edited. Sorry!! How about now?

@J.N. now its how I understood it originally. Do you know what locally finite means? It means for every $x$ there is an open set around $x$ which intersects only finitely many $C_n$.

As for the union, your friend might be wrong but they are raising a good point. When we write $\infty$ in the upper index we don't mean to include $C_\infty$ in our union. Its a slight abuse of notation.

@Jakobian Oh, thank you for those clarifications. So you anyway confirm that the two notations are the same? I mean I know that $\infty$ is not a number hence I wouldn't include it, except as a limit

Yes, the notations mean the same thing. Somewhat confusingly $\bigcup_{n=1}^m C_n$ is meant to include $C_m$, but not when $m$ is explicitly said to be $\infty$ :P

for $D_n$, an easy argument is that a convergent sequence in $\cup D_n$ is bounded (by some 2N), and therefore its support is included in $D_1 \cup . . . \cup D_N$. Which is a finite union of closed sets, so closed. so its limit is in $D_1 \cup ... \cup D_N$

The set $C$ is not closed, since $(0,0)\notin C$, but $(0,0)\in\overline C$. This is so because, for each $n\in\Bbb N$, $\left(\frac1{2n},0\right)\in C_n\subset C$ and $(0,0)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac1{2n},0\right)$.
But $D$ is closed. If $(x,y)\in\overline D$, then $(x,y)=\lim_{k\to\infty}(x_k,y_k)$ for some sequence $\bigl((x_k,y_k)\bigr)_{k\in\Bbb N}$ of elements of $D$. Take the open ball $B_1\bigl((x,y)\bigr)$ with center $(x,y)$ and radius $1$. Then,$$(z,t)\in B_1\bigl((x,y)\bigr)\implies\|(z,t)\|<\|(x,y)\|+1.$$Take $N\in\Bbb N$ such that $2N\geqslant\|(x,y)\|+1$ and that $n\geqslant N\implies(x_n,y_n)\in B_1\bigl((x,y)\bigr)$ (such an $N$ must exist, since $(x,y)=\lim_{k\to\infty}(x_k,y_k)$). Then $n\geqslant N\implies(x_n,y_n)\in\bigcup_{k=1}^nD_k$, and so$$(x,y)\in\overline{\bigcup_{n=1}^ND_n}=\bigcup_{n=1}^N\overline{D_n}=\bigcup_{n=1}^ND_n\subset D.$$

Thank you so much, I'll study this answer. Sorry again for the errors in my question...
